# Get http requests using enum list in parameter value

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am new to APIs. Trying to send a get request for the following API (https://docs.deribit.com/#authentication-2).

The website gives an example authentication request, for which I should receive a JSON response.

`curl -X GET "https://test.deribit.com/api/v2/public/auth?client_id=fo7WAPRm4P&client_secret=W0H6FJW4IRPZ1MOQ8FP6KMC5RZDUUKXS&grant_type=client_credentials"` 
`-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

I try the following in Python:

```
import requests
import json
import os
import hmac
from hashlib import sha256

api_name = 'foo'
client_id = 'bar'
client_secret = 'foo1'
ip_whitelist = 'bar2'


url = f'https://test.deribit.com/api/v2'
path_dir = os.getcwd().replace(' ','')

client_signature = hmac.new(bytes(client_secret, 'utf-8'), b'', sha256)
# params = {'client_id': client_id, 'client_secret': client_secret, 'client_signature': client_signature}
params = {'client_id': client_id, 'client_secret': client_secret, 'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

I get `Response[400]`. If I print `r.url`, I am getting the same url as the example, with my credentials:

`'https://test.deribit.com/api/v2/public/auth?client_id=foo&client_secret=bar&grant_type=client_credentials'`

I then reread the documentation and paid attention to the `grant_type`

[image: Documentation]

Which says that the parameter `grant_type` should have the `client_signature`, `refresh_token` and `client_credentials`. Can someone please explain this to me?